# Including a number in gtk3 widget

Tags: c, widget, gtk, gtk3

I'm doing a Matrix program and I have done a widget for entering the dimension but I want to show the numbers into the widget and I don't know how.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
static int d,e;
void on_button_click(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{if ((char *) data=="1")
    {d=d+1; }
    if ((char *) data=="2")
    {d=d-1;}
    if ((char *) data=="3")
    { e=e+1; }
    if ((char *) data=="4")
    { e=e-1; }
    g_print("The dimension is height: %d y width : %d\n",d,e);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{ GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *table;
  GtkWidget *label;
  GtkWidget *frame;
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv){
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Start ...");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
  table = gtk_table_new (3,4,FALSE);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("More x");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK (on_button_click), (gpointer) "1");
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE(table),button,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,2);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Less x");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_click), (gpointer) "2");
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE (table),button,1,2,0,1,0,0,2,2);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("More y");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_click), (gpointer) "3");
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE(table),button,2,3,0,1,0,0,2,2);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Less y");
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_button_click), (gpointer) "4");
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE(table),button,2,3,0,3,0,0,2,2);
  button=gtk_button_new_with_label ("Quit");
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE (table),button,0,2,1,2,0,0,2,2);
  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT(window),"destroy",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (G_OBJECT(button),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit),(gpointer)window);
  frame=gtk_frame_new(NULL);
  label=gtk_label_new("Columns x\n Rows y");
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(frame),label);
  gtk_table_attach(GTK_TABLE(table),frame,3,4,0,2,GTK_EXPAND|GTK_FILL, GTK_EXPAND|GTK_FILL,0,0);
  frame=gtk_frame_new(NULL);
  label=gtk_label_new("Redim the matrix... ");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER(frame),label);
  gtk_table_attach (GTK_TABLE(table),frame,0,4,2,3,GTK_EXPAND|GTK_FILL, GTK_EXPAND|GTK_FILL,0,0);
gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();

return 0;
}
      ...
```

The problem is that the variables `d` and `e` appeared in the console when I clicked one of the four buttons.  For me it doesn't matter because the program ran anyway. But I believe that it looks better if the two numbers appear into the widget in a box.

Comment: `(char *) data=="1"` is a bad comparison, it's not guaranteed that `data` will point to the exact same location as `"1"` use `strcmp` / `strcasecmp` for string comparisons.

Comment: @marco-a - `strcasecmp()` is not in the C or C++ standard.  It is POSIX only.  You'ld want to consider using `strcmp()` if it needs to be C.

Comment: @marco-a using a strcmp to check the char in a single character string is overkill. `*(char *) data=='1'` is sufficient

Comment: @0___________ It's not overkill, if you really want to compare strings. `(char *)whatever == "some string"` is always wrong. Why do you say it's overkill? I'm saying comparing strings like that is wrong, not that OP should do it that way.

Comment: @0___________ Your comment is really unnecessary, at least when directed to me. It's not me that made the choice to implement the code that way.

Comment: @ryyker I didn't know that `strcasecmp` is POSIX. Whatever, my point still stands: it's wrong to compare strings like that.